# Calculate direction in PostGIS & Django (GeoDjango)

Tags: postgis, geodjango, django

Is it possible to calculate direction to detect if users are moving in "similar" direction having a few of their last coordinates (Points) using PostGIS + Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/gis/)?

I couldn't find information about this feature.

Answer (score 0):

What you're calling "direction" I think corresponds to the angle relative to the north, aka azimuth. Apparently, there is a function in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#azimuth

Then you just need to compare the 2 angles to see if they are close. Don't forget it's modulo 2*pi (it is a bit tricky, for example see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878907/how-can-i-find-the-smallest-difference-between-two-angles-around-a-point)).

Comment: Could you please briefly explain how to user GeoDjango's Azimuth function, it's not well explained in docs for me, maybe you could share any tutorial or explanation? How do I get **the angle relative** to the north using Azimuth, I mean I'm passing points to it but do not know what to do next :/

Comment: You're passing point A and point B, and you get the angle relative to the north of the segment A->B. You can see it as a clock, A is the center, B is the pointer extremity, and it gives you the hour: if you get pi/2 radian it's like it's 3 o'clock, and if you get 3pi/2 it's 9 o'clock.
From there you can compare the 2 angles, as I said be carefull when they are close to 0: 0.01 is an angle really close to 2*pi-0,01, see the link or google "how to compare 2 angles in python"

Comment: yeah, but when it comes to code(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Azimuth), how do I get the actual value. When I pass two points I receive instance Azimuth(Value(<Point object at 0x23295e5b288>), Value(<Point object at 0x23295e5b308>)), how do I get the actual angle?